# Book navigation block?

Tags: blocks, 8, nodes

Where is the book navigation block in Drupal 8?

The structure guide for Drupal 7 says you just need to turn the navigation menu on by enabling the block.

> ...One navigational aid you can use is the book navigation block,
>   which you can enable on the blocks page administer >> site building >>
>   blocks (Drupal 5 and 6) or Dashboard >> Structure >> Blocks (Drupal
>   7). Enabling this block will turn on a menu that shows where the user
>   is in your book; the menu is only visible when viewing the book.

But there doesn't appear to be a "book navigation block" in Drupal 8 as far as I can see.

Where is this block hiding in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to click on one of the "Place Block" buttons displayed beside all the region names, a popup with all the unused blocks appears and you select it from the list to add it.

Comment: You should accept your own answer.